# Using node package outside of node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I'm making a chrome extension that uses Firebase database. For their custom authentication I need to create a JWT token to have the user sign in.

I saw on their documentation that their is a function to generate these tokens in node using the function call:

`var customToken = firebase.auth().createCustomToken(uid);`

My issue is that my chrome extension is not a node app, so I don't have access to this function. I have the firebase auth API from their CDN but when I try using that function I get `firebase.auth(...).createCustomToken is not a function`.

I guess that the create JWT token function is just for node.js firebase users. Is there a way I can still get access to this token generator without my extension being a node app?

I'm new to this JWT stuff so really I'm just looking for an easy way to generate one of these tokens somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a custom token requires access to the service account of your Firebase project. This is a server-side secret and should never be present in the clients that access your project. If you give your clients the secret needed to mint a custom token, you're giving them full access to your project. You might as well not use authentication in that case.

The typical approach is to run a [server that mints a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens) based on your app's needs and then [use that token in your client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth) (e.g. a chrome extension) to sign in.

Alternatively you can use one of the built-in authentication methods, such as [email+password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth), [Facebook](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login), [Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin) or even [anonymous sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth).

Comment: My plan is to generate a random string when a user first uses the extension. Then I use that string to generate a JWT token and sign him up using that. I'll keep a secure part of the database that maps these random strings to their in-game username. That way I can use firebase's rules to only allow the person with the correctly generated random string to access their section of the database.

Comment: That sounds suspiciously close to anonymous sign-in. I highly recommend using that instead of rolling your own in a non-secure way.

Comment: I'd love to just use anonymous sign in, but I don't know how I would take advantage of the database rules then. If every time a client used the extension he'd anonymously sign-in, would there be any sort of persistent data in their auth object that I could use to map out to their in-game username? Or would it be a random uid every time? I need some sort of way to hook up a client's auth object with their in-game name, which is why I thought my approach made sense. However, if I could do the same thing with anonymous sign-in I'd much rather use that.

Comment: Yup. The Firebase client persists the token between sessions, so the `uid` would be the same as long as you don't call `signInAnonymously()` again.

Comment: Oh wow that's great news! I don't have to deal with JWT tokens :)